# How can I convert Excel XML to HTML using xslt?

Tags: html, xml, excel, xslt

I have xls-file in format Excel XML (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=101).

How can I convert to HTML using xslt or how to generate xslt-file to Excel?

Comment: If you are looking for a single XSLT that works with any files, then I fear that could be extremely complicated. If, however, you only need it for certain situations, it may be possible, but you at least need to edit your question to show a sample of the Excel XML, and the HTML you would expect to be output. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
                version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:element name="style">
    <xsl:for-each select="ss:Workbook/ss:Styles/ss:Style">
    #<xsl:value-of select="@ss:ID"/>
    {
        <xsl:if test="ss:Alignment/@ss:Horizontal">
            text-align: <xsl:value-of select="ss:Alignment/@ss:Horizontal"/>;
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="ss:Alignment/@ss:Vertical">
            vertical-align: <xsl:value-of select="ss:Alignment/@ss:Vertical"/>;
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="ss:Alignment/@ss:Vertical">
            vertical-align: <xsl:value-of select="ss:Alignment/@ss:Vertical"/>;
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="ss:Font/@ss:Bold=1">
            font-weight: bold;
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="ss:Font/@ss:Color">
            color:<xsl:value-of select="ss:Font/@ss:Color"/>;
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="ss:Font/@ss:StrikeThrough=1">
            text-decoration:line-through
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="ss:Font/@ss:Underline='Single'">
            text-decoration:underline
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="ss:Interior/@ss:Color">
            background-color:<xsl:value-of select="ss:Interior/@ss:Color"/>;
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:for-each select="ss:Borders/ss:Border">
            <xsl:if test="@ss:Color">
                border-<xsl:value-of select="@ss:Position"/>-color:<xsl:value-of select="@ss:Color"/>;
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="@ss:Weight">
                border-<xsl:value-of select="@ss:Position"/>-width:<xsl:value-of select="@ss:Weight"/>px;
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="@ss:LineStyle">
                border-<xsl:value-of select="@ss:Position"/>-style:<xsl:value-of select="@ss:LineStyle"/>;
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
}
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="table">
        <xsl:for-each select="ss:Workbook/ss:Worksheet/ss:Table/ss:Row">
            <xsl:element name="tr">

                <xsl:for-each select="ss:Cell">
                    <xsl:element name="td">
                        <xsl:attribute name="id">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@ss:StyleID"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:if test="@ss:MergeAcross">
                            <xsl:attribute name="colspan">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@ss:MergeAcross+1"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ss:Data"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use XSLT to generate HTML from EXCEL. You have to get your Excel data into an XML format first and then use XSLT to generate HTML.

To get XML from EXCEL you could use Java: http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/
I am sure it is possible in other programming languages as well.

You could use the following java code then to convert your EXCEL to XML:

```
public static void convertXLS() {

    File file = new File("C:/tesco_invoices_zwe02.xls");
    Workbook wb;
    try {
        wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(file);
        String xmldata = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n\n"
                + "<ns0:" + "bla" + " " + "xmlns:ns0=\"" + "bla" + "\">";
        Cell[] cells;
        Cell[] cellNames;
        cellNames = wb.getSheet(0).getRow(0);
        for (int j = 1; j < wb.getSheet(0).getRows(); j++) {
            xmldata = xmldata + "<Recordset>";
            cells = wb.getSheet(0).getRow(j);
            for (int i = 0; i < wb.getSheet(0).getColumns(); i++) {

                String cellcontent = cells[i].getContents();
                String cellcontent2 = cellcontent.trim();
                
                xmldata = xmldata
                        + "<"+ cellNames[i].getContents()+ ">"+ cellcontent2 + "</" + cellNames[i].getContents() + ">" + "\n";
            }
            xmldata = xmldata + "</Recordset>";
            
        }
        
        xmldata = xmldata + "</ns0:" + "bla" + ">";
        wb.close();
        System.out.println(xmldata);
    } catch (BiffException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: I believe the question is refering to Excel Spreadsheet XML, which is format that Microsoft Excel can save to when saving a spreadsheet. As it is XML, it is perfectly feasible to run XSLT on it, although it may not necessarily be simple XSLT.

Comment: Hello Tim, you are right. I misunderstood the question expecting to have data in form of EXCEL format *.xls. The OP should give us an example of his input and expected output then.